# Get Data through relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using this query to get data using relation

```
 return Product::with('attributes')
        ->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($attribute_id,$attribute_value){
            $query->whereIn('attribute_id', $attribute_id);
            $query->whereIn('value', $attribute_value);
        })
        ->paginate(10);
```

$attribute_id and $attribute_value are arrays, i'm getting data using this relation but when $attribute_id and $attribute_value are empty then i'm not getting any result but it should return result through product table if there are no attributes.

I have changed it to something like this:

```
 if(!empty($attribute_id))
                {
                    $query->whereIn('attribute_id', $attribute_id);
                }
                if(!empty($attribute_value))
                {
                    $query->whereIn('value', $attribute_value);
                }
```

> model relation :

```
 public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductsAttribute::class, 'product_id ');
    }
```

Table:

```
id | Title     | Price

1    Title 1     5000
2    Product 2   7000
```

this is related to product_attribute table

```
id | product_id | attribute_id | attribute_name | value
 1     1              5             Color         Red
 2     1              6             Size           XL
 3     2              5             Color         Green
```

Is there any other way to make a check in query so that if attributes are not provided then atleast product data should return.

Comment: As far as I know, this is the normal Laravel Query Builder function. If you pass an empty array to a `whereIn` condition, it will return an empty collection.

Comment: @tamrat: Is there any other way if attributes is empty then it should return all the Products without filtering data but in current scenario if attribute array empty it is not returning any data from products

Comment: Check out my answer. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner way might be to use local scopes. That way, your controllers will look *cleaner*. It also makes the code easily testable. Here is how I might approach this.

***NOTE**: Code hasn't been tesed.*

In your controller:

```php
return Product::with([
  'attributes' => function ($query) use ($attribute_id, $attribute_value) {
    return $query->inAttributeId($attribute_id)
                 ->inAttributeValue($attribute_value);
  }
])->paginate(10);
```

In your **ProductsAttribute** model:

```php
public function scopeInAttributeId($query, $attributeId)
{
  if (empty($attributeId)) {
    return $query;
  }

  return $query->whereIn('attribute_id', $attributeId);
}

public function scopeInAttributeValue($query, $attributeValue)
{
  if (empty($attributeValue)) {
    return $query;
  }

  return $query->whereIn('value', $attributeValue);
}
```

As you can see, the scopes modify the query only if there are values in the passed in array. If the passed in array is empty, it returns the original query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have checked by implementing in my code, if no attributes are passed then it is returning all data but if i try to filter it by attributes then also it returns all data

Comment: I had a typo in the `scopeInAttributeValue` scope. The code is checking for `attribute_id` in both cases. Could that be the problem?